# RelativeSource Sibling

Tags: wpf, relativesource

Below tabitem3 is working fine.
I would like to get away from naming the controls and pass the properties by RelativeSource.

The code that is failing is

```
Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}" Path="IsExpanded"
```

The error in the converter is dependency object not set

The Expander is a sibling not an ancestor.
How can I find that sibling (without an x:Name)?

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabitem3" IsSelected="False">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Expander x:Name="tabexp3" Header="Three" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                  Expanded="expcolp" Collapsed="expcolp" IsExpanded="False"/>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Content Three TabItem" Background="LightBlue" >
        <TextBlock.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource bvc2}" Mode="OneWay">
                 <Binding ElementName="tabexp3"  Path="IsExpanded"/>
                 <Binding ElementName="tabitem3" Path="IsSelected" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Visibility>
    </TextBlock>
</TabItem>
<TabItem IsSelected="False">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <Expander Header="Four" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                  Expanded="expcolp" Collapsed="expcolp" IsExpanded="False"/>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Content Four TabItem" Background="LightBlue" >
        <TextBlock.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource bvc2}" Mode="OneWay">
                 <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}" Path="IsExpanded"/>
                 <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}"  Path="IsSelected"/>                          
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Visibility>
    </TextBlock>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Just curious why don't what to use naming?

Comment: @Gosha So I don't have to create unique names for each TabItem.   So I could use it in control that it added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that Expander is a real sibling of the TextBlock. The first one is a child of TabItem's header, the former is a child of TabItem's content.

Anyway if you do not want to use naming (indeed I do not like it too), you can "go up" through the logical tree by looking for a `TabItem` ancestor and then you can "go down" by using the right path.

The result is this binding:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}" Path="Header.IsExpanded" />
```

I hope it can help you.

**EDIT**

To test my binding you can use this simple XAML:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem IsSelected="True">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Expander Header="One" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsExpanded="False"/>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Some contents..." />
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem IsSelected="False">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Expander Header="Two" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsExpanded="False"/>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}" Path="Header.IsExpanded" />
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

If you expand/collapse the second Expander, the TextBlock's text will change.
My binding does not work if the TabItem has `IsSelected` set to true. In this case you can extend my idea in this way:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}" Path="SelectedItem.Header.IsExpanded" />
```